# Specifying a global variable outside of function

Tags: php

I have a pretty long extensive function, and the only thing that would change for me to use it elsewhere in the application would be to change the `global` variable declared inside of it.

```
function some_function() {
  global $sys;

  // ... Do stuff

}

some_function();
```

I need to change `global $sys;` to `global $lang;` or possibly a few other things, but everything else would stay the same. I was thinking something like:

```
function some_function($global_var) {
  global $global_var;

  // ... Do stuff

}

some_function($sys);
```

... or maybe ...

```
some_function($lang);
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You want to change the global's name? or the value?

Comment: @Hanoncs sorry I'm having a hard time explaining this. I want to be able to declare a different global variable inside of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `global`, you could just pass the "global var" as a parameter to the function by reference:

```
function some_function(&$global_var) {

    // ... Do stuff

}
```

Then you could use this function elsewhere without requiring to change the "global var" name.

Answer (score 0):

Also consider the `use` keyword to import a variable from outside the scope instead of working in the global scope.